# Cocos2d: Add collision to a uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision

I have cocos2d integrated into my project with interface builder. In inferface builder I have a uiimageview of a ball. I want to add collision properties from cocos2d to the ball image as well as restitution, friction, etc. I have the cocos2d Box2d template that has a box with all the properties I need but I don't know how to implement these properties on to the ball in my interface builder. Any help on how to do this is appreciated.
Or, on another note, would Sprite Kit be a better solution for this manner?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/606 see this tut.

Comment: put physics body with respect to your uiimageview.